# Failed to upgrade lock from read to write state, please re-try the configuration operation

Tags: geoserver, geoserver-css-module

I have been working with Geoserver and today I was not able to perform any operations in it. The error message says that,

> > "Failed to upgrade lock from read to write state, please re-try the configuration operation"

I have no idea about this error. Could anyone help me with this?

NB: I already tried restarting the OS.

Comment: are you on a Windows machine? try deleting the css and related files from the data_dir/styles directory.

Comment: @IanTurton Could you please specify the exact path?

Comment: not with out knowing where and how you installed GeoServer - it is in **your** data directory

Comment: Thank you all for the comments. The problem was due to the cache. Once the server was restarted, the problem was handled.